# Show only the own console messages and errors (JS)

Tags: javascript, filter, console, console.log

I use several JS files that I don't have access to and write all over my console.

But I only want to display my own message with `console.log("Own message.")` and errors (e.g. `404 error`).

If I use `console.clear` before the log function, directly but also **all error messages are cleared**.


Is there a way to filter console messages to show only errors or the own message and errors?

I have already heard that there are certain libraries for this.

Is it also possible without?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chrome, you can just type in the name of your JavaScript file to filter for messages that only come from that file. For example, I had some console messages, and then I typed in `userscript` to only display logs that came from `userscript.html`:

[image]

Firefox has the same sort of filtering box too.

No need for any libraries.

To display messages from multiple multiple possible sources but no others (for example, to show only messages from `foo` and `bar`), use a regular expression, eg:

```
/foo|bar/
```

in the same filter box.

Comment: This actually solves my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Can filter the logs, but seems like new logs coming in after filtering does not appear in the filtered result, only when I clear the filter and readding it, I can see it (I can see all when I clear filter)